# Nomenclature+amsart: compile error if PDF output is long but not if it is short

Tags: mactex, nomenclature, amsart

Using the nomenclature package with amsart, I get a compiling error if the PDF output is long but not if it is short. Here is the shortest example of the problem I could make.

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex "\jobname.nlo" -s nomencl.ist -o "\jobname.nls"}
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makenomenclature                                                           

\begin{document}
\title{Nomenclature error} 
\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\nomenclature[Lx]{L}{The distribution of random variable $X$.}
We write $\mathcal{L}_X$ for the distribution of $X$. 

\lipsum 
\lipsum
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Using the "Typset" command in TeXShop 4.42, with a fresh MacTeX install (from mactex-20190508.pkg, downloaded just this morning). The second time I run "Typset" the console gives me the following.

```
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2017/10/31 v2.20.4
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nomencl/nomencl.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(./mwe.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) (./mwe.toc)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [2]
(./mwe.nls)
./mwe.tex:21: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \list@fname 

l.21 \end{document}

?
```

If I hit return to ignore the error the compile completes with correct output.

The same error occurs if I replace \printnomenclature with the content of the file mwe.nls, which is the following:

```
\begin{thenomenclature} 
\nomgroup{L}
  \item [{L}]\begingroup The distribution of random variable $X$.\nomeqref {0}\nompageref{1}

\end{thenomenclature}
```

However, if in the main TeX file I include the \lipsum command just **one** time rather than two times, the error does not occur.

The error also doesn't occur if I use article rather than amsart.

Comment: can't reproduce your problem. your code works fine for me. I get the same `underful` warning, but that can be ignored (but it's best to deal with warnings the same way as with errors). have you run an update on your packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the short and long version is that on page 3 the code tries to write the name of the nomenclature in the header. And as amsart does a number of unusual things something clashes.

Possible workarounds:

```
\usepackage[notocbasic]{nomencl}
```

or

```
\makeatletter\let\list@fname\nomname \makeatother
```

Comment: The main problem seems to be that `amsart` redefines `\@starttoc` to take two arguments instead of one, while `tocbasic` expects the standard definition. I'd go with `notocbasic`.

Comment: notocbasic solved the problem for me. I tried to read the doc of package nomencl but I do not understand what are the implications of switching off this option. In fact I do not see why toc stuff is involved in the default mode notintoc.